# Using netcat in a batch file why the output remains in the console even when redirected?

Tags: batch-file, netcat

I have a batch file and an excerpt of the code below. 
The code is used to test port on specific host.

The code shown below has an intentional error (www**w**.google.com) that I am trying to redirect to a file for later treatment. Even if I redirect all outputs to the file the following is still shown in the console :

"wwww.google.com: forward host lookup failed: h_errno 11001: HOST_NOT_FOUND"

I would like to catch this error in the file rather than showing it to the console...Not sure why the redirects aren't working ?

```
@echo off
set tempFile=%temp%\temp

call :CheckPort "wwww.google.com" "80"
GOTO :EOF

:CheckPort
nc -z %~1 %~2^>%tempFile% 2^>^&1
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: why the escapes? try `nc -z %~1 %~2 > %tempFile% 2>&1`

Comment: Thank you I just tried and it worked. I was using the command in a for /f in ('nc...') earlier and > was unexcepted within the for command context so I had to escape. Thanks again, basic mistake :)

Comment: I will post an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escaping of the characters will break the pipe. instead do:

```
nc -z %~1 %~2 > %tempFile% 2>&1
```

which will redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` and `STDOUT` to file, meaning both will go to file.

Comment: When adding the verbose option (-v) it doesn't work however `nc -zv %~1 %~2 > %tempFile% 2>&1`

Comment: because verbose is meant to output.